# How to read the value in $ussdResponse->Message

Tags: json

Am developing USSD application which uses JSON API. My problem is that, I can't read the value entered by the user.

I have tried this method but it returns "Invalid JSON response type" from the server.

```
<?php

    $ussdRequest = json_decode(@file_get_contents('php://input'));

       header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

       $ussdResponse = new stdclass;

       if ($ussdRequest != NULL)

          switch ($ussdRequest->Type) {

            case 'Initiation':
                   $ussdResponse->Message =  'Enter your full name: ';
                   $ussdResponse->Type = 'Response';
               $msg = $ussdResponse->Message;
                  break;

                 case 'Response':

                switch ($ussdRequest->Sequence) {

                     case 2:
                          $ussdResponse->Message = 'The message is: '+ $msg;
                             break;
                           }

              }

        echo json_encode($ussdResponse);

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! First, what is ussd? Also, what is the specific error you're experiencing? It's hard for anyone to help without more information.

Comment: It would also be good to see the data shape. If you echo back the JSON to the browser, is it well-formed? Can you share a copy of the data if it's not confidential?

Comment: No, it is not well formed. The response from the server is  "The USSD service you tried to reach returned an invalid response. Please contact the USSD service provider. Error UUE" The error means "Invalid JSON response type"

Comment: USSD means Unstructured Supplementary Service Data. I want to get the user's name and save it into a database using PHP PDO connection string.